# Why doesn't the singular verb “pass” take an “-es” suffix in this sentence?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

As I was studying Peterson’s *Master TOEFL Writing Skill*, I saw the sentence:

> Teamwork requires that a player **pass** the ball whoever is in the best position to make the goal.

I wonder why *pass* does not take an *-es* suffix in the sentence cited above. Is it a mistake? If not, could you please explain under which particular circumstances we don’t add *-es* suffix to a present tense verb that’s in the third-person singular?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16179/use-of-subjunctive-with-in-order-that

Comment: I think it's not much related.

Comment: This has been addressed in several questions here, perhaps best in [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76550/why-is-this-sentence-correct-she-suggested-that-he-go-to-the-cinema/76551#76551). It's traditionally called the *mandative subjunctive*, implying that a tense called the 'present subjunctive' is in play in clauses expressing an action commanded or required; but many contemporary theorists prefer to see the verb form as a bare infinitive. The use was at one time common; it still is common in US English, and is experiencing a resurgence in British English.

Comment: @StoneyB The problem with your tag is that tag is the answer, not the question.

Comment: @tchrist  That is true, and I had not looked at it that way before. I'll fix.

Comment: @StoneyB: Would you please provide a reference or two for the different analyses and the frequencies of usage over time? (My excuse for not doing the research myself is that I've got to go house-hunting with my daughter.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here’s my source for current use: Leech et al [*Change in Contemporary English*](http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Leech%20G.%20Change%20in%20Contemporary%20English.pdf), Cambridge UP 2009. A discussion by Arnold Zwicky of terminology is on [LanguageLog](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001192.html).

Comment: Thank you. These look very interesting. It's going to be a real wrench switching to - er, checking plumbing.