# What is the difference between "in order to" and just "to"?

Tags: meaning

> 1. He invited me to dinner to discuss her future.
> 2. He invited me to dinner in order to discuss her future.

> 3. He impressed his boss to get a promotion.
> 4. He impressed his boss in order to get a promotion.

Is there any difference between each of the sentences in each pair?

Comment: We don’t say “disscuss about”.   First of all, “discuss” has only one ‘s’ in the first syllable.   If you changed “disscuss about” to “discuss” or “talk about”, then, yes, the pairs of sentences would mean pretty much the same things.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost always replace 'in order to' with 'to'. So yes, both sentences mean the same thing. 
Ideally, you would use 'in order to' when you specifically wish to stress on the intent or purpose of something, depending on the context.

Comment: Not satisfied sir

Comment: I found another thread with a detailed discussion on this. Hope that helps.   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/in-order-to-to-or-for